# Multi threading issues with database

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency

I want to parse a file and transfer the content into a database. To speed up everything the file should be parsed parallel.
I have a main thread which is reading a file line by line and create *Runnable*, which are given to a *ThreadPoolExecutor*. Each *Runnable* gets its own *Session*.

Each line contains an unique identfier for a client, so repition is possible. The system tries to find the client in the database by the identifier.
If it can't be found one of the threads wanting the same client need to create the client. I have here a "join" point, where other threads have to wait for the thread which is allowed to create the client.

```
c = (Client) s.get("Client", identfier);
if (c == null) {
    CountDownLatch lock = isClientResolutionActive(identfier);

    if (lock != null) {
        lock.await();
        LOGGER.info("Lock was released ... " + identfier);
        c = (Client) s.get("Client", identfier);
    }
}

if (c == null) {
    c = createClient(...);

    s.save(c);
    s.flush();
    removeClientResolutionActive(identfier);
}
```

To synchronise them I have created two methods in the caller class, one method is dedicated to check if there is already someone doing the client creation and returns the shared object and the other removes the entry from the list and notify all waiting threads.

I have searched a lot in the internet and tried to find my problem or a similar issue without success.
Furthermore I am not sure which concurrency object I should use. After research I have decided for the *CountDownLatch*. It is initialized with **1**. There should only be one thread creating it. (Perhaps it would be better to use something else than the *CountDownLatch*, but I don't know what)

The above described methods contain a **synchronized** block on the map, which holds the identifier of the client and the instance of *CountDownLatch*.

```
private CountDownLatch isClientResolutionActive(String identfier) {
    synchronized (activeSearches) {
        if (activeSearches.containsKey(identfier)) {
            // Only create the CountDownLatch if there are multiple threads for
            // that identfier
            if (activeSearches.get(identfier) == null) {
                activeSearches.put(identfier, new CountDownLatch(1));
            }
            return activeSearches.get(identfier);
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Locked " + identfier);
            activeSearches.put(identfier, null);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

private void removeClientResolutionActive(String identfier) {
    synchronized (activeSearches) {
        CountDownLatch cl = activeSearches.get(identfier);
        activeSearches.remove(identfier);
        if (cl != null) {
            LOGGER.info("Unlock " + identfier);
            cl.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

In general it works fine, but sometimes I encounter the problem, when the latch is released (and deleted) and the access-synchronized-variable-queue contains another thread to search for the deleted entry (to check if any thread is doing it already), it tries to create again a new client.

```
18:02:55,611 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO LogImporter Unlock b42fcae346fbb2b1e3c544fb816de2c5
18:02:55,611 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO LogImporter Locked b42fcae346fbb2b1e3c544fb816de2c5
18:02:55,611 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO LogImporter Lock was released ... b42fcae346fbb2b1e3c544fb816de2c5
```

I think I have to improve the synchronization, but I have no ideas how.

One idea would be to move the client search into the **synchronized** block or check before locking against the database again.
Perhaps create a cache or map, which holds all known clients from database.
Or use only one *Session* the whole lifecycle of the app?

Thanks in advance for any advices and hints.

Comment: I don't understand why in removeClientResolutionActive you remove the CountDownLatch even if it is non-zero!?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you don't create a CounDownLatch for the first call. It's like you try to set it to 'null' like you want to preserve some memory.

Comment: After the remove I call the `countdown` method. I have some threads but it doesn't mean that all threads needs the same client. If there is a second try to get the call you know there are two threads.

Comment: But second or first (or third) thread will remove the count down. So it is useless. Next thread will not find it. (I talk about thread working on same client).

Comment: The idea was that only one thread can create the client and remove the latch. For that there is a `get` after the `lock.await`.

Comment: In the text description you are talking about identifier, but in the code you use `hash`. Are they the same thing?

Comment: Yes it is the same. I have edited my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parsing the same file in parallel threads does NOT add speed but just costs extra ressources

A less problematic and more efficient text2db optimisation consists of:

- bulk read the file (rather then line by line read 1 MB at once, process it, read next MB)
- bulk insert into the database - mysql like this:

  ```
  insert into urtable 
  values
  ('val1','val2'),
  ('val1','val2');
  ```

(example stolen from http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/585793-insert-into-using-select-values-inserting-multiple-rows - sorry for being too lazy to make one up by myself)

- try to prevent sql back and forth (means: if select-output is required from the database to enrich your dataset read it upfront and not on and on while walking through the file)

UPDATE ----

From the comment I took that there might be a need to get data from the database, while parsing the file. Well, if you have to do, you have to do. BUT: Try to not have to do that.

First of all: Reading specific data can be seen caching or not. In a narrow understanding caching is just moving disk data to memory by any heuristics (without knowing what is going on). I personally try to avoid this because heuristics can play against you. In a wider understanding caching is what I described before PLUS put data from disk to memory, which you can pinpoint down (eg. by ID or any filter criteria). So I still do not like the narrow understanding part of this but the behaviour selecting well defined data upfront.

Secondly: My personal experiences go like that: IF you are working on a fully normalized data model database read operations in file parsings very often cook down to 'give me the primary key(s)' of what I dumped before into the database. This appears to become tricky when you write multiple rows at once. However especially in MySQL you can definitely rely on 'each insert statement (even multiple row inserts) is atomistic', you get the ID from last_insert_id() and so you can track this down to all your previously written records. I am pretty sure there are similar 'cock downs' for other database systems.

Thirdly: Parsing LARGE files is something I would try to operate as job with only ONE technical user triggering that with ensuring that NOT >1 of these processes run in parallel. Otherwise you need to work around all sort of issues starting with file locking going into sessions permission read/write management. So running this as job classifies this (at least in my personal policies) to allocate LOTS of RAM - depending on costs and how important speed is. That means I would not even bother to load a 100 K row keyword-to-id table into memory upfront.

Comment: So the last point is creating a Cache from the database? What about objects which are stored in the database while parsing the file?

Comment: Thanks. :) I noticed I should use written instead of stored in my sentence. The database is growing while parsing the file.

Comment: @CSchulz: Not sure, what you mean? Dependent objects? What is the issue? Mixing reads and writes to the database is not a big deal in itself. I just wanted to point out, that it makes sense to optimize the read/write - data is a matter of memory (RAM), not of cpu time (which people seem to think can be stretched by parallel threads)

Comment: While parsing a file clients which couldn't be found will be created in the database. The entry table has a relation to the client table.

Comment: @CSchulz: What is your client's unique names (the ones you get from the log file)? Is this IP or IPtoInt-converted numbers? Which type of keys you got in the relating table (numberIDs or strings)? Could you preload your clientName-to-clientID table into an array (this is a question of potential table size and available script memory)?

Comment: It is indeed the IP but in hashed form (so it is a string). I don't save the IP so the clientName-to-clientID table "isn't possible". But the question is what about new clients?

Comment: @CSchulz: An IP is unique by definition. There is no need to fittle with an 'IP master table' and stringy bits and pieces like hashes. Preferably you change your data model and use and IP4ToInt algo to transform IPs into number keys (eg. the IP 100.101.102.103 transforms into INT by (100 << 24) & (101 << 16) & (102 << 8) & 103). Once you got this any table relating to client IP4ToINT converted keys will always be correct. Of cause you can make up INT keys from IP6s as well. Another benefit would be that you can render an INTToIP4 at any time.

Comment: Okay I understand the benefits. I will change it. :) But in general how does it help me with the "problem"?

Comment: @CSchulz:the benefit is less round trips to the database which ultimately improves your overall performance. My whole answer goes like this: tweak your script RIGHT, which does NOT include multi-tasking/threading. The tweaking bit are: bulk reads and write PLUS employ only db round trips which are really needed PLUS improve scaling (which involves to ensure that script only running once at a time but then assign it LOTs of memory) PLUS use arrays for intelligent 'caching' rather then make use of any heuristic caching